# IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device while installing TensorFlow

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip, tensorflow

I am trying to install TensorFlow in my local directory using the following command.

```
export TF_BINARY_URL=http://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PYTHONUSERBASE" --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

I am getting the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

Then I did `df` to see the following:

```
Filesystem             1K-blocks       Used   Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                      10240      10240           0 100% /tmp
tmpfs                      10240      10240           0 100% /var/tmp
```

Is there a way I can install TF without the temp files being downloaded in `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`? Thanks.

Answer (score 64):

Usually, You can set the environment variable 'TMPDIR' to use a different directory other than /tmp or /var/tmp and most programs will honour that.

You can perhaps try,

> $ export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp

and then start your 'pip install'

Comment: Great suggestion, and easy to use.

I would further suggest you run it more like this:

`TMPDIR=tmp pip install <package>`

As you may forget the export later on, if in the same shell.

Comment: Be sure to make the folder: `mkdir -p $TMPDIR` Not doing this cause issues for me.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html

Comment: Your solution worked in my case @lingfish

Answer (score 16):

You might be able to use 'pip install -b /some/other/dir' which changes the build dir.

You can also change the wheel dir as can be seen here
https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#installation-bundles

Running `pip help install` will get you the other dir options as well.

```
-b, --build <dir>           Directory to unpack packages into and build in.
-t, --target <dir>          Install packages into <dir>. By default this will not replace existing files/folders in <dir>. Use --upgrade to replace existing packages in <dir> with new versions.
-d, --download <dir>        Download packages into <dir> instead of installing them, regardless of what is already installed.
--src <dir>                 Directory to check out editable projects into. The default in a virtualenv is "<venv path>/src". The default for global installs is "<current dir>/src".
```

Comment: -b --build has been deprecated and compilation of C files is still done in the TMPDIR when setting the --build flag. Setting the 'TMPDIR' did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

```
export TMPDIR=/bigspace/space
```

Why?:
It is likely that  /tmp directory do not have enough space for some reason.

During the pip installation, pip will use /tmp directory to perform what is necessary to perform installation (e.g. download source etc).

Thus if you do not have enough space in /tmp that package installation requires then you will get disk space error.

You can configure your  /tmp directory location using below command

Answer (score 5):

Create tmp folder on /home/myuser then execute in Terminal "export TMPDIR=/home/$USER/tmp"

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1:**
Pip won't re-download the package in this solution but in other solutions it does

Check the available disk space using `df -h`:

If you just need to change tmpfs size, you can remount it on-line with new size:

```
$ sudo mount -o remount,size=10G /tmp
$ sudo mount -o remount,size=10G /var/tmp
```

**Solution 2:**
You can set the environment variable 'TMPDIR' for pip

```
$ export TMPDIR=$HOME/new/tmp/dir
$ pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PYTHONUSERBASE" --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

**Solution 3:**
With custom cache/temp directory

```
$ pip install --cache-dir=$HOME/new/tmp/dir/  --install-option="--prefix=$PYTHONUSERBASE" --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

**Solution 4:**
With no cache directory

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --install-option="--prefix=$PYTHONUSERBASE" --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for python3.9 and pip 23.1.

You need to set the variable `TMPDIR` and specify the `--cache-dir` option.

```
TMPDIR=/mybigtemp pip3 --cache-dir /mybigtemp  install tensorflow tensorflow_probability
```

See all pip install options in the help:

```
pip3 help install
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is $TMPDIR default set to `/tmp` and your `/tmp` space is limited.

You can fix this issue by `mkdir` at another path (such as `/space/enough/tmp/`) with enough then run below one line command:

`TMPDIR=/space/enough/tmp/ python -m pip install --install-option="--prefix=$PYTHONUSERBASE" --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

`