# pip install and pip download fail with no space error, despite there being plenty of space

Tags: python, download, pip, installation

I've been having issue getting `pip install` to run so that I can install tensorflow in an existing envrionment. However, it has been crashing with a no space error. In my research, I found that pip, by default, downloads its packages to /tmp.  Since that is under the root directory, I tried doing a pip download for an offline installation, with the files being downloaded into a directory under /home.  This failed with the same error.

```
pip download --no-cache-dir tensorflow -d /home/profile1/tmp/

#downloads several packages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/download.py", line 135, in run
    resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
    discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
    abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
    abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 287, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes,
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 164, in unpack_http_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/unpacking.py", line 252, in unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/unpacking.py", line 139, in unzip_file
    shutil.copyfileobj(fp, destfp)
  File "/home/profile1/anaconda3/envs/testinstall/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfileobj
    fdst.write(buf)
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

On using `df -h /home', I see that I have 20 GB left in the file system, so this does not make any sense. Is there anything else I can do as far as remediation goes?

I was also able to confirm that this is only with pip; I was able to use conda install to get tensorflow, but not pip.  In addition, I found the same error when trying to download torch.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755610/ioerror-errno-28-no-space-left-on-device-while-installing-tensorflow) will help?

Comment: I'll need to try this; however, other people use this server, so I'll need to clear it with them first, incase changing TMPDIR has an effect on them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the /tmp directory being full.
There're a few workarounds for this issue:

- Clean the /tmp directory from unnecessary files.
- Set the TMPDIR environment variable to another directory and then run pip.
- See if you can increase the space for the /tmp directory through likes gpart(ed).

Comment: 1.  I'll try TMPDIR at some point and get back to you; as I mentioned to @Redline, I'm not the only person using this server, so I can't just do this at my own discretion.

2.  I checked the /tmp directory, and it still has 1.8 GB available.  To be certain, I tried downloading torch with pip, which is about 700-800 MB; I still got the same error.

3.  I'm redirecting the download to a tmp folder under /home, which has 20GB available.  Also, this /tmp directory is empty.

Comment: @svill Are you able to install a simple small package with pip? Anyway it should be obvious that 800 MB of a downloaded package will take much more size when it's unpacked, as the wheel has to be compiled and then installed. I had similar issues with the /tmp directory while installing Android Studio.