# Correspondence between Python and pip versions

Tags: python, pip

I have to install Tensorflow and the object detection API on a Jetson NANO.
I generally manage everything with virtual environments, but for a bunch of reasons this time I had to install everything in the base environment, and I assume I might've messed
something up.

The process starts, but it's getting stuck on solving some dependencies issues, and after running for the whole night it returns an error regarding the space left on the device (I assume it's downloading multiple versions of different packages and running out of space). So, I'm wondering if I'm installing them correctly.

I tried running the command:

```
python3 -m pip3 install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
```

but I'm getting the error:

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip3
```

If I run simply

```
python3 -m pip install --use-feature=2020-resolver .
```

it goes, but as I was saying it gets stuck, so I was wondering if it is installing the files in the right locations.

I tried checking the outputs of:

```
which python3
which pip3
```

and I got

```
/usr/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
```

So, the command pip3 does exist, and refers to /usr/local/bin/pip3...at this point, I don't understand why it returns the error when trying to use python3 -m pip3 install.
As a matter of fact, I used pip3 for all the previous steps in the object detection API installation, like:

```
sudo pip3 install -U pip testresources setuptools==49.6.0
sudo pip3 install -U numpy==1.16.1 future==0.18.2 mock==3.0.5 h5py==2.10.0 keras_preprocessing==1.1.1 keras_applications==1.0.8 gast==0.2.2 futures protobuf pybind11
sudo pip3 install --pre --extra-index-url https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/redist/jp/v45 tensorflow
```

(I generally DON'T use sudo with pip, just following the official instructions for the Jetson NANO)

Comment: did you try just `pip3 install` something?

Comment: Yes, works without problems, I edited the question regarding this.

Comment: `python -m pip` runs the pip _module_. There is no module called `pip3`, only a module called `pip`, so `python -m pip3` will not work. `/usr/local/bin/pip3`, on the other hand, is a _command_, which happens to be a shortcut to running the `pip` module in your Python installation. On Linux the command has been named `pip3` to avoid problems between Python 2 and 3, but this has no relation to the naming of the `pip` module.

Comment: I'm sorry, so this means that using python3 -m pip install is basically invoking pip3? Same as installing stuff by using pip3 install random-package?

Comment: "and after running for the whole night it returns an error regarding the space left on the device" this is the real error here

Comment: I can try again after freeing up some space, but the process has been trying to download  previous scipy and pandas versions for hours, which usually doesn't happen (it went down to VERY old ones), so I was assuming there was some problem in where these things were being installed.

Comment: @Carlo Yes, the commands `python3 -m pip install random-package` and `pip3 install random-package` are equivalent. Under the hood, they both run the `pip` module in the Python 3 installation.

Comment: Sometimes there can be an issue where `pip3` and `python3` point to different Python installations, but unless you have installed multiple Python versions on your Jetson NANO this is likely not your problem.

Comment: Was your error message `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`? If so, there is a good chance that Tensorflow is running out of space in the /tmp folder when trying to compile stuff. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40755610/ioerror-errno-28-no-space-left-on-device-while-installing-tensorflow) for possible workarounds.

Comment: Yes, precisely, that was the error. Thanks, I'll check the answer you linked and try running the installation once more, but I still find it suspicious that it's collecting all those versions down to very old ones. I mean, if it does, it's because the more recent version are found to be incompatible? That shouldn't be happening.