python package installation via pip gives: ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
I am trying to install FlagEmbeddings (https://github.com/FlagOpen/FlagEmbedding)
like so:
git clone https://github.com/FlagOpen/FlagEmbedding.git
cd FlagEmbedding
pip install -e .

I am running into:
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

I am running a virtual machine on azure
output of df -h is as follows:
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        29G   28G  1.6G  95% /
devtmpfs         63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs            63G  4.0K   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            13G  1.1M   13G   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       64M   64M     0 100% /snap/core20/2318
/dev/loop3       39M   39M     0 100% /snap/snapd/21759
/dev/loop1       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/24061
/dev/sda15      105M  6.1M   99M   6% /boot/efi
/dev/loop2       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/lxd/29619
/dev/sdb1       590G   32K  560G   1% /mnt
tmpfs            13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/1000

What can I do to resolve the error? I am open to provisioning more resources from azure if that is what it takes

Point $TMPDIR to a partition that has more space. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40757314/7976758 for an example. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+OSError%3A+Errno+28+No+space+left+on+device

The filesystem reserves usually about 5% of space on the filesystem for the root user and to maintain good performance (see reserved space for root on a filesystem), so the 1.6 GB you see as free might not be available for you to use. You'll need to make more space on the disk, which means either cleaning up unnecessary files or provisioning more resources.
